# Foundation issue between buildings

Tags: prison-architect

I have a cell block that I want to connect to a newer cell block. I created the foundation, then wanted to create a secure inside tunnel (with regular foundation) between the two for ease of workers, guards, etc, putting jail doors on both sides. I selected the foundation tool and created a path between, but it complained that an entrance was required, even though both ends have a large jail door.

After the fact, I realized that I didn't make it wide enough because the foundation includes the walls, so I wanted to remove it, but now I can't interact with it at all. I can't demolish what's there, and no workers (even when completely idle) will not work on it. I'm not sure what my options are now. I'd be fine deleting the path between the cell blocks if I can, so I can have another attempt at creating one.

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated on either how to finish the path with foundation (not just concrete tiles) or delete what's there.

Comment: There's currently a bug with removing unfinished buildings. The steel beams still show up even after you cancel the building. If you try to add grass or dirt over that spot, what happens?

Comment: @walrushelmet that did the trick! I was able to add grass tile over top of the beams, then was able to add more concrete foundation (extending it above and below the actual path by 1 each) and it worked exactly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment above:

There's currently a bug with removing unfinished buildings. Steel beams still appear even after cancelling the build command. Adding a new outdoor floor such as grass or dirt over that spot will clear the construction area.